# Tensor product of subalgebra

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, algebras

Let $R$ be a ring and $A, B, C$ $R$-algebras such that there is an injective $R$-algebra Homomorphism $i: B \hookrightarrow C$. Is it true that the induced map $j: A \otimes_R B \to A \otimes_R C$ is injective?

As @Mohan has pointed out the answer to this is negative. Does the situation change if we replace $R$ by a field $k$?

Comment: Try $R=B=\mathbb{Z}$, $C=\mathbb{Q}$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime $p$.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you. Do you know if the answer change if we replace $R$ by a field?

Comment: Yes, it changes.

Comment: As @user26857 says, it changes. If $R$ is a field, $j$ is injective. A sufficient condition is that $A$ is $R$-flat. Over a field, everything is flat.